# MySQL выборка с подстановкой пустых значений

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица **expenceslist**, содержащая статьи расходов (expence_id, expence_name), и таблица **expences**, содержащая фактические расходы, с указанием статьи расхода (expence_id), суммы расхода (expence_amount) и месяц, в котором был понесен расход. Как можно выбрать расходы таким образом, чтобы MySQL вернула перечень всех возможных статей расхода с указанием суммы и периода, причем если расхода с таким именем в таблице расходов нет, был бы указан 0?
Пример того, что нужно:

| Расход | Январь | Февраль | Март |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Администратор | 10000 | 0 | 10000 |
| Фотограф | 0 | 20000 | 15000 |
| Оператор | 0 | 0 | 10000 |

Comment: Странно, почему в предпросмотре таблица нормально отображается, а после публикации съезжает?

Comment: *если расхода с таким именем в таблице расходов нет, был бы указан 0* `COALESCE()` *почему в предпросмотре таблица нормально отображается, а после публикации съезжает?* Нет зазора (пустой строки)

Comment: Не разобрался с COALESCE()

Comment: При LEFT JOIN и отсутствии записи справа в поле `column_name` будет NULL. `COALESCE(column_name, default_value)` позволяет заменить этот NULL на заданное значение. Например, в Вашем случае это может быть ноль: `COALESCE(column_name, 0) AS column_name`.

Comment: У меня не получается сделать выборку так, как нужно. Помогите готовым решением.

Comment: Выкладывайте исходные - CREATE TABLE таблиц, INSERT INTO с образцом данных, и требуемый ответ для этих данных.